# Notificaiton progressbar produces sound on update Android

Tags: android, notifications

I have been updating Notification Progress-bar like this. This is called multiple times. But Notification sound is produced multiple times. Which is annoying

```
     builder.setProgress(100, percentage, false); 
     notificationManager.notify(notifycation.notificationId, notifycation.builder.build());
```

Here is Notification Code

```
    public void initProgressNotificaiton(Context context) {

    notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, ChannelId);
    builder.setContentTitle("Video Upload")
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentText("Upload in progress")
            .setSound(null)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.upload)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW);
    
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
    
}
```

Channel Code

```
    public void createNotificationChannel(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = "naem";
        String description = "desc";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(ChannelId, name, importance);
        channel.setSound(null, null);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
```

How do i fix that? Tested on API 30 Emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a flag to alert only once.

Try this:

```
Notification notification = builder.build();
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```